# Is this sentence correct? Do or does?

Tags: verbs

"I am hoping for an idealistic world which do/does not exist"

What should I use here? Do or does? Also please tell where do I learn these basic concepts?

Answer (score 1):

"Does"

Rule: Singular nouns (an idealistic world) take singular verbs (does) after them; Plural nouns (idealistic worlds) take plural verbs (do) after them.